# 100% height and width Div "absolute positioned" eats my footer?

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

The problem came about because the div `#backgr-box` has to be `position:absolute` so that its background can be be behind the content `#contenuto` thanks to z-index. But now the footer disappears behind `#backgr-box` when the div `#contenuto` is too short in content to push it down.

Any solution out there? I also tried with a fixed height for `#contenuto` and JavaScript instead of `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

On #backgr-box change `height: 100%;` to `height: auto;`

On #footer do `margin: 170px auto 0;`

I believe this will fix the issues you're having.  I'm sure this is not the best way to fix it, but on my end it does work.

Hope this helps.